# File.Exists returns true and OpenExisting fails with DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

I am tring to open memory mapped file in the system volume information subfolder. I know and see in explorer that it is exists there, and path is correct (it is copy-pasted from explorer), moreover File.Exists for that path returns true, but MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting fails with DirectoryNotFoundException. Why? (I have all rights to system volume information folder and subfolders).

Some code:

```
const string filePath = @"C:\\System Volume Information\\Foo\\2.ext";

bool exists = File.Exists(filePath); //is true
using (MemoryMappedFile bitmapFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(filePath, MemoryMappedFileRights.Read)) //Throws DirectoryNotFoundException
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("yourPathToFileInDisk", FileMode.Open,"WhateverName")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createfromfile(v=vs.110).aspx) which is opening file you need. [MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("WhateverName")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.openexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) tries to open already existing memory mapped file.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used these APIs, but I believe you need to map the file to memory first. Try MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile